# How to emulate Javascript `super` so `new.target` is defined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to emulate this javascript without using the ES6 keywords (e.g. without `class`, `super` or `extends`):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    if (!new.target) 
      console.log('Foo() must be called with new');
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }
}

var bar = new Bar();
var barIsFoo = bar instanceof Foo;
console.log(barIsFoo); // true
```

I got this far, but they're not equivalent. The following throws (I log instead) while the latter does not:

```js
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) 
      console.log('Foo() must be called with new');
}

function Bar() {
  Foo.apply(this, arguments)
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;

var bar = new Bar();
var barIsFoo = bar instanceof Foo;
console.log(barIsFoo);
```

So, how do I emulate providing a value for `new.target` when I call into `Foo` from `Bar`?

---

So, seems there's no `apply` or `call` that allows passing the `new.target`. I suppose that would defeat the purpose of `new.target` (though the fact that everything in JS is public really appealed to me).

So to emulate in ES5 we'd need to add something.

One solution in an answer below allocates a new object.

This solution adds new functions `construct` which can be chained as usual in ES5 and leave the function itself free to do nothing more than check if it's being used as a constructor.

```js
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) 
    throw 'Foo() must be called with new';
  console.log('Foo new check');
  Foo.prototype.construct.apply(this, arguments);
}
Foo.prototype.construct = function() {
  console.log('Foo construction logic');
}

function Bar() {
  if (!new.target) 
    throw 'Bar() must be called with new';
  console.log('Bar new check');
  Bar.prototype.construct.apply(this, arguments);
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
Bar.prototype.construct = function() {
  // super()
  Foo.prototype.construct.apply(this, arguments);

  console.log('Bar construction logic');
}

var bar = new Bar();
var barIsFoo = bar instanceof Foo;
console.log(barIsFoo);
```

Bottom line, it appears ES6 features not **not** just syntactic sugar over ES5. Of course, they could just add a `Function.prototype.super(target, arguments, newTarget)` and then we could just use that. I hope they do!

---

Only `super` can call a function in Javascript and have `this` not be available immediately. So `super` is unique. And `super` can only be called in the context of a `constructor` which can only be used in the context of a `class`. Sooo all those key words are necessary to make `super` work. So Javascript has introduced a very specific object oriented feature. Looks like building a language on top of the idea of a "prototype" has it's limits.

Which is a shame...

I wonder why, all of a sudden, javascript decided to enforce this one invariant. That `this` is not available before the `super` call. Why not just make `super` a short hand for `BaseType.prototype.constructor.call(this, ...)`. Why not allow it to be invoked more than once? We can blow our toes off so many other ways in Javascript, why start enforcing things now?

Well, anyway...

So, double bottom line, there exists a early bound Javascript call `super` that has no late bound equivalent (unlike, for example, `foo.bar()` which can be called late(r)bound via `bar.call('foo')`).

Comment: Yikes. Is it [this complicated](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#constructor-calls-explained-via-javascript-code) under the hood? What the heck is __construct__?!

Comment: Here's the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects) section discussion FunctionAllocate that the above blog references as explaining how this works with `super`. I find it impenetrable but include it for the sake of SO completeness.

Comment: This IS built on top of the idea of prototyping; that’s just javascript, and classes are syntactic sugar. Anyway, it’s a problem that polyfills can solve. I’m not sure how it works anymore, but you should choose one or the other, in mixed case.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Object.assign` to assign the parent constructor's `new Foo(...arguments)` to the instance:

```js
function Foo(arg) {
  if (!new.target) 
    throw 'Foo() must be called with new';
  this.arg = arg;
  this.fooProp = 'fooProp';
}

function Bar() {
  Object.assign(
    this,
    new Foo(...arguments)
  );
  this.barProp = 'barProp';
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;

var bar = new Bar('abc');
var barIsFoo = bar instanceof Foo;
console.log(barIsFoo);
console.log(bar);
```

But `new Foo(...arguments)` is ES6 syntax. To translate that to ES5, instead use

```
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Foo, [null, ...arguments]))()
```

(which takes care of the `new` part), which again transpiles down to

```
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Foo, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))))()
```

```js
function Foo(arg) {
  if (!new.target) 
    throw 'Foo() must be called with new';
  this.arg = arg;
  this.fooProp = 'fooProp';
}

function Bar() {
  Object.assign(
    this,
    new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Foo, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))))()
  );
  this.barProp = 'barProp';
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;

var bar = new Bar('abc');
var barIsFoo = bar instanceof Foo;
console.log(barIsFoo);
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, but also I wonder what if he tries `Bar.prototype = new Foo()`?

Comment: @LeroyStav Then the properties assigned in `Foo`'s constructor (which *should* be on the instance) will actually be on the prototype, which isn't desirable.

Comment: When I run this code under a debugger I find that `bar` does not have property `fooProp` defined. That's unexpected, right?

Comment: @ChristopherKing Oh, that's right, `(this)` won't work because `this` is already `Foo` in the inner `apply`, have to use something like `Object.assign` instead (`Object.assign is ES6, but it's trivial to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) for ES5 compatibility)

Comment: But then we'd be allocating another object in the ES5 code that's not allocated in the ES6 code, right? I'm under the impression that ES6 is just "syntactic sugar" over some equivalent ES5 code. And if that's the case then there should be a solution that doesn't involve allocating another object. Or is that not the case?

Comment: Thats not *entirely* correct.  *effectively*, yes, it is syntactic sugar.  However in actuality, it behaves differently.  Very specifically it behaves differently *in regards to new.target*.  Your question was *very* interesting and honestly, I think @CertainPerformance 's solution is pretty much as close as you'll get to what is actually going on behind the scenes.  I will add (and correct me if I'm wrong), however, that Object.assign is a *shallow* copy, so *technically*, any array or object defined on Foo and copied to Bar has two references, the first of which is quickly garbage collected.

Comment: @ChristopherKing I don't think there's any way around creating an extra object, because the `new` operator is required, which will create a separate object no matter what. Many features in ES6 cannot be expressed equivalently in ES5 *without creating extra variables*, but that shuoldn't be something to worry about - polyfills do that all the time, but the implementation can still be faithful to the spec.

Comment: Ok so something has been bothering me and I ran a quick test... on the one hand, based on my understanding of javascript your code should work, but I've never thought to try something like this so I didn't know for *sure* it would. On the other, it is clear that Foo isn't *actually* called with any arguments (tho the bind *should* set them...) So I tested it.  It seems like the arguments are lost

Comment: The joke is that `(Function.bind.apply(Foo))(...arguments)` *does* work, but we're right back to es6, so why bother? :-D

Comment: @LeroyStav Spread is perfectly transpilable syntax sugar, so [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to the rescue!

Comment: Doubt it. They almost certainly use either Object.assign or Function.apply, both of which don't work in this case...

Comment: @LeroyStav `apply` *does* work (see last line of answer), it's just ugly, and `Object.assign` is polyfillable

Comment: OK!!!! In my defense it was, like, 2am for me.  I was going crazy because I knew what you had *should work* but couldn't figure out why it wasn't.  `bind` *and* `apply` means you have to `(Foo, [null, ...arguments])`!  Only one small thing, no need for the `()` at the end, there... `new Foo()();` :-D

Comment: Using `assign` resets `enumerable` and `configurable` flags that may have been set by the base class, no? So it's not quite faithful to the spec, yet. We'd have to enumerate the descriptors and re-assign them, right?

Answer (score 1):

ES6 class syntax is not syntax sugar for ES5, but it *is* pretty much syntax sugar for other ES6 functionality.

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }
}
```

is pretty similar to if you did

```
let Bar = function(...args) {
  const _this = Reflect.construct(Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar), args, new.target);
  return _this;
};
Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, Foo);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar.prototype, Foo.prototype);
```

where `Reflect.construct` constructs and object with a given `new.target` value and calls a given constructor with a set of arguments.

Comment: Each call to `Reflect.construct` allocates a new object right? So in a deeper prototype chain/hierarchy there'd be no way to chain the calls together so they can pass `new.target` while at the same time acting on the same `this`, no? So, if we were to make "no additional allocations" a requirement then that would preclude `Reflect.construct` right?

Comment: In an ES6 class, the object is created by the deepest constructor, so there _is_ no `this` until the parent constructor has been called. You are right that this example would allocate and then discard an extra `this` object. There is no way to avoid that.

Comment: Yep. I see that by using the `class` keyword I can defer `this` creation till the deepest constructor. I was wondering if there were a way to emulate that behavior without using the keyword but doesn't appear so. The `class` keyword is pretty special. That's funny too because why not provide a function that passes the `new.target` as just another argument? We can blow our toes off in every other way in JS. Why not that way?

Comment: I thought, "Why not `Function.prototype.super(target, arguments, newTarget)`?" Yet, that wouldn't work because, as you say, target is deferred... so even if I could add a method, what would it be? Hm.. Another way to think about it would be to ask if it's possible to derive from an ES6 `class` without using `extends`.. Maybe `Reflect.construct` makes at least that possible.. Hm.. have to think about that.. thx!

Answer (score 0):

To write abstract classes, you need to make sure that the constructor of the parent class is called in the context of the prototype of the called class.
To do this, ES6 introduced "Reflect.construct".

For ES5, you can implement your own "crutch".

```js
// Reflect.construct simulation for ES5
class Reflect2 {
    static construct(TargetClass,args,ProtoClass){
        let oldProto= TargetClass.prototype;
        let desc=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(TargetClass,'prototype');
        if(desc.hasOwnProperty('value') && desc.writable===false){
            if(desc.configurable===true){
                desc.writable=true;
                Object.defineProperty(TargetClass,'prototype',desc);
            }
        }
        TargetClass.prototype=ProtoClass.prototype;
        let self=new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(TargetClass,args));
        TargetClass.prototype=oldProto;
        return self;
    }
}
function ParentClass(){
}
ParentClass.prototype.constructor=ParentClass;
function MyClass(){
    if(new.target===undefined){throw Error();}
    let self=Reflect2.construct (ParentClass,[],new.target);
    // your code
    return self;
}
MyClass.prototype=Object.create(ParentClass.prototype,{
    constructor:{
        value:MyClass
    }
});
let a=new MyClass();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a)===MyClass.prototype);
```

"super" in ES6 is the same "this", but in the context of the parent prototype. For example, when we bind an object to a function via "bind ()", here we bind object "this" only to the prototype object.
"super" can be implemented in 2 ways:

- through prototype scanning, and binding to methods and reactive properties of the 'this' object;
- via Proxy object

Emulation 'super' in ES6
via Proxy object

```js
/**
* @param {object} self - this object  
* @param {function} ProtoClass - the class to observe.  
 Usually the current class for which methods are being written.  
* @param {function} [new_target]  used in the constructor.   
If not passed, then the default will be the prototype constructor for "self" 
 (Object.getPrototyprOf(self).constructor).
* @param {boolean} [bindSelf] - if true, then the methods and reactive properties 
 of the parent will work in the context of self, if false, then the methods and  
reactive properties will work within the framework of the object in which they  
are called (i.e. within the Proxy object).
*/
function Super(self,ProtoClass,new_target,bindSelf=false){
    let parentProto=Object.getPrototypeOf(ProtoClass.prototype);
    let descs={};
    // collect descriptors of all prototypes
    do {
        let buf=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(parentProto);
        for(let prop of Object.keys(buf)){
            if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(descs,prop)){
                descs[prop]=buf[prop];
            }
        }          
        parentProto=Object.getPrototypeOf(parentProto);
    }while (parentProto!==null); 

    // we define the control object
    let answer={};
    let new_obj=function (...args){
       let ParentClass=Object.getPrototypeOf(ProtoClass.prototype).constructor;
       if(ParentClass===Object || ProtoClass===ParentClass){
            return self;
       }
       new_target=new_target??Object.getPrototypeOf(self).constructor;
       return Reflect.construct(ParentClass,args,new_target);
    } 
    
    let parent=new Proxy(self,{
        get(target,prop){
            let desc=descs[prop];
            if(desc===undefined){
                return;
            }
            if(desc.hasOwnProperty('value')){
                if(bindSelf && typeof desc.value==='function'){
                    return desc.value.bind(target);
                }
                return desc.value;
            } else
            if(desc.hasOwnProperty('get')){
                return desc.get.call(target);
            }
        },
        set(target,prop,value){
            let desc=descs[prop];
            if(desc===undefined || desc.hasOwnProperty('value')){
                target[prop]=value;
                return true;
            }
            if(desc.hasOwnProperty('set')){
                desc.set.call(target,value);
                return true;
            } 
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperties(answer,{
        new:{
            value:new_obj
        },
        parent:{
            value:parent
         }
    });
    return answer;
}
```

How to use

```js
function A(...args){
}
A.prototype.method=function(){
    console.log('hello',this);
    return this;
}
A.prototype.constructor=A;
function B(...args){
    if(new.target===undefined){throw Error();}
    let _super=Super(this,B,new.target);
    let self= _super.new(...args);
    let b=_super.parent.method(); // return proxy object
    /*
        in this case, all execution inside the method will occur as if this has a parent prototype.
    */
    console.log(b===this);// false  
    return self;
}
B.prototype=Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor=B;
B.prototype.method=function(){
    console.log('bay');
    return this;
}
let b=new B();
```

or

```js
function A(...args){
}
A.prototype.method=function(){
    console.log('hello',this);
    return this;
}
A.prototype.constructor=A;
function B(...args){
    if(new.target===undefined){throw Error();}
    /*
    we want the methods to execute against the "this" context 
    and not in the "new Proxy ('this', {})" context
    */
    let _super=Super(this,B,new.target,true);// arg[3] true
    let self= _super.new(...args);
    let b=_super.parent.method(); // return this object
    console.log(b===this);// true  
    return self;
}
B.prototype=Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor=B;
B.prototype.method=function(){
    console.log('bay');
    return this;
}
let b=new B();
```

for ES5 Proxies can be replaced with a regular object, where “this” through “bind” is bound to methods.

```js
function Super(self,ProtoClass,new_target){
    let parentProto=Object.getPrototypeOf(ProtoClass.prototype);
    let parent={};
    // properties all prototypes
    do {
        let buf=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(parentProto);
        for(let prop of Object.keys(buf)){
            if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(parent,prop)){
                let desc=buf[prop];
                if(buf[prop].hasOwnProperty('get') ){
                    desc.get=buf[prop].get.bind(self);
                }
                if(buf[prop].hasOwnProperty('set') ){
                    desc.set=buf[prop].set.bind(self);
                }
                if(buf[prop].hasOwnProperty('value') ){
                    if (typeof buf[prop].value === 'function') {
                         desc.value=buf[prop].value.bind(self);
                    } else{
                        delete desc.value;  
                        delete desc.writable;
                        desc.get=function (){
                            return buf[prop];
                        };
                        desc.set=function(v){
                            self[prop]=v;
                        };
                    }
                }
                Object.defineProperty(parent,prop,desc);
            }
        }          
        parentProto=Object.getPrototypeOf(parentProto);
    } while (parentProto!==null); 

    // we define the control object
    let answer={};
    let new_obj=function (){
       let ParentClass=Object.getPrototypeOf(ProtoClass.prototype).constructor;
       if(ParentClass===Object || ProtoClass===ParentClass){
            return self;
       }
       new_target=new_target??Object.getPrototypeOf(self).constructor;
       // We described the "Reflect.construct method" above. see Reflect2.construct
       return Reflect.construct(ParentClass,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),new_target);
    } 
    Object.defineProperties(answer,{
        new:{
            value:new_obj
        },
        parent:{
            value:parent
         }
    });
    return answer;
}
```

Example

```js
function A(...args){
}
A.prototype.method=function(){
    console.log('hello',this);
    return this;
}
A.prototype.constructor=A;
function B(...args){
    if(new.target===undefined){throw Error();}
    let _super=Super(this,B,new.target);
    let self= _super.new(...args);
    let b=_super.parent.method();
    console.log(b===this);
    return self;
}
B.prototype=Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor=B;
B.prototype.method=function(){
    console.log('bay');
    return this;
}
let b=new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using `if (!new.target)`  is  to check if the `Foo` is called with `new`(as a constructor), in which case we can just use `if(this instanceof Foo)` instead.

`this` could be an instance of `Foo` or `Bar`, and whether you call `new Foo()` or `Foo.apply(this)`, the `this instanceof Foo` can always return `true` while it will return `false` if you just call `Foo()`(without `new` or `apply`/`call`).

Try this:

```js
function Foo() {
  if (!this instanceof Foo) 
      console.log('Foo() must be called with new');
}

function Bar() {
  Foo.apply(this, arguments)
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;

var bar = new Bar();
var barIsFoo = bar instanceof Foo;
console.log(barIsFoo);
```